# Where can I find Texas Instruments article for basic building componets?

Tags: circuit-design, texas-instruments

I was searching web for some good reading material and I found [this](https://mega.nz/file/RfQESbjL#2JFyguawzU8yKQv1VBrxfdLopLUiRRT2anf5Edouh1c) article by Texas Instruments.
Now I'm wondering where i can find TI archive for this kind of stuff?

Subject of article is not important, I will read everything.

Comment: TI has a vast range of application notes [here](https://www.ti.com/technical-documents).  Some are very general, some are very narrow in focus.

Comment: I found some books from TI - analog engineers cookbook - amplifiers and opamps.  Another book is Op amps for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [here](https://training.ti.com/search-catalog) where published by TI to training and learning on various subjects. Maybe It is what you are looking for.